# Shiny GUI in Java

Tags: java, user-interface

Is there any library I can use to create shiny user interfaces in Java?

e.g. The Intel Graphics & Media Control Panel is written in .Net.

[Intel Graphics & Media Control Panel](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/img/mainscreen.jpg)

I want to know how to create such UI in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use and customize your UI with Swing.
Nowdays there is also JavaFx 2.0.

Also there are a lot of extensions like those from SwingLabs,JGoodies,Jide,Glazed List and the amazing Substance look& feel ,Steel Series etc.

Just google for this terms you get a lot of useful links.

http://download.oracle.com/javafx/

http://www.jgoodies.com/

http://swingx.java.net/

http://java.net/projects/substance/

http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/

Be aware is not easy and out of the box functionality but you can do anything.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Swing user interfaces use a look and feel called ['Metal'](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

You could try making your own look and feel to accomplish something similar.

Comment: *"By default, Swing user interfaces use a look and feel called 'Nimbus'."* I don't think this is true... The default one is "Metal" (AFAIK)

Comment: The default look and feel is typically referred to as "Java LAF" or "Metal".

Comment: Alright, I've edited my answer. I thought Nimbus became the new LnF.